# Unobtrusive Windows Notifications

Tags: c++, windows

I'm looking for a simple solution to create an unobtrusive notification program for windows using c++/QT/WinAPI/SDL or any other quick library. I'm wondering what the fastest method (as far as development goes) to create a simple program that pops a quick window up with access to a larger gui interface if clicked.

Is there a quick and easy way to set something up like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [Growl for Windows](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/).